# Can I use install for personalization two times for a SD?

Tags: embedded, applet, smartcard, javacard

I couldn't find in Global Platform Specifications v2.3.1. neither Global Platform Common Implementation Configurations what happens when I:

- Install for personalization a Applet SD with AID1 first time
- Install for personalization a Applet SD with same AID1 second time
  (AID1 could be anything, is for clarify the question)

I understand that the first install for personalization would open a Personalization Session and the second would close this session and will open another one as specified in '11.11.1 Store Data command'

```
A personalization session ends when:
- The Security Domain receives an INSTALL [for personalization] command (starting a new personalization session for another application)
```

For my understanding, it should work if we are installing for personalization two times. What it means 'for another application'? Could it be the same? Different? Which exception should we need to use?